# How to join two lists like this in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations

I've these two lists `a = [1, 2, 3]` and another `b = [4, 2, 1]`

I want this outcome by join these list like this (items in a with every item of b) :

```
(1, 4) (1, 2) (1, 1)
(2, 4) (2, 2) (2, 1)
(3, 4) (3, 2) (3, 1)
```

Comment: You could use a nested loop. This seems like homework. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+python+tuples+cartesian+product+two+arrays) of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533905/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

For generating the cartesian product:

```
cart_prod = [(i, j) for i in a for j in b]
```

---

**EDIT** the question changed

```
>>> for i in a:
...   print([(i, j) for j in b])
...
[(1, 4), (1, 2), (1, 1)]
[(2, 4), (2, 2), (2, 1)]
[(3, 4), (3, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: As someone with enough rep to cast close votes, why answer this basic question rather than VTC as a duplicate of the many similar questions asked before?

Comment: You are right Sebastian, this could be the first Python answer I am giving